# Redefine __str__ method in the same way for multiple classes in Python

Tags: python, class, object, methods, printing

I have multiple classes and if I instantiate any of them, I want to be able to "print" the instantiated object by redefining the **str** method for these classes. The **str** method would be the exact same for all classes and I don't want to repeat this method under every class. How can I do this for all classes and not have to have **str** defined under each? Would a class decorator help here?

```
class testClass1:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.value + 5)

class testClass2:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.value + 5)

test1 = testClass1(2)
print(test1)
```

Comment: You could create a class decorator, or you use inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a parent class that has the functionality you want and inherit it in each of the child classes:

```
class Stringer:
    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.value + 5))
    
class testClass1(Stringer):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class testClass2(Stringer):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

test1 = testClass1(2)
print(test1)
#7 

test2 = testClass2(5)
print(test2)
#10
```

Comment: Yes, that works. I was wondering if there was way to do it without inheritance.